# Good programming practices in C, why and how does it affect declaring a counter outside a loop, and why its better to do it?

Tags: c

I want to increase my good practices at programming, specially the ones related to code legibility.

I would like to ask why some people says (in my case university teacher) says that declaring a counter outside a loop (for example, a for loop), its better than declaring the counter while creating the loop, here you have two examples of what I mean:

Declaring a counter while creating a loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    //stuff
}
```

Declaring a counter outside a loop:

```
int i = 0;

for (i; i<10; i++){

//stuff
}
```

So, after seeing this, I would like to as I said above, understand why people says doing the second way is better, and if possible, get an explanation on how does it affect when compiling the program, it makes the program less big regarding size? Or its just a way to make the code more legible? I'm kinda lost, and i would like to get clarified with this.

Comment: It has to do with scope and variable lifetime. Declared in the loop declaration, `i` is local to the loop and goes out of scope when the loop completes. Declared outside the loop it survives until the end of the the enclosing block. If you need `i` after the loop, declare it outside, if not, declare it as part of the loop. (e.g. say you are iterating placing characters in an array and want to nul-terminate using the loop variable after the loop terminates, e.g. `string[i] = 0;` -- `i` must be declared outside the loop) There is no better/worse practice involved -- it's variable lifetime...

Comment: IMO it is best to minimize the scope and lifetime of variables whenever you can. If a variable doesn't exist you can't use it by mistake or shadow it and mistakenly use the wrong one.

Comment: OT: `for (i; i<10; i++){` should be `for( ; i < 10; i++ ) {`... Any of the 3 expressions of `for()` may be left blank... No need to confuse the compiler or your reader with a no-op like only naming `i` to fill the gap... (Adding whitespace around operators and between brackets&braces improves legibility, too!)

Answer (score 3):

Use below when `i` is not needed after the loop.  Minimize the scope of `i`.

```c
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    //stuff
}
```

Use below when `i` is needed after the loop.

```c
int i = 0;
for (; i<10; i++){
  //stuff
  // Maybe exit early due to some condition.
}

// Use `i`
```

Or, use this to keep the loop related parts together (initialization, condition, loop statement).

```c
int i;
for (i = 0; i<10; i++){
  //stuff
  // Maybe exit early due to some condition.
}

// Use `i`
```

Answer (score 2):

C was developed around 1970 when 32kb RAM was a luxury. Early compilers couldn't read the entire function into memory to determine how big a stack frame should be. They needed you to declare local variables up front, and simply didn't support declaring them in for loops.

The C99 standard changed this, but not until 1999, and it was considered avant-guard for years after.

Today you're free to use any style you consider more readable, which is generally declaring the variable in the for loop to limit its scope.

Comment: I see, so basically the thing is that people in 1970 declared variables outside loops, so they will save RAM? At least, that's what i understood, however today is not needed anymore because we have enough RAM to handle declaring variables in loops, am i correct?

Comment: It saved RAM for the compiler, not for the program. The memory usage of the program is not affected.

Comment: You could always declare variables within blocks, both after statements like `if` or `for`, as well as arbitrary blocks only to limit variable scope. The small compilers would make several passes, and one pass would flatten the parse tree, another would determine stack size from that. Declarations were at the top of a block because structured languages would have an explicit declaration section, C just made that implicit for simplicity. Fortran allowed declarations anywhere, and it was the earliest compiled language.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, good practice is sticking to a style and using it consistently throughout your code.

At my University, (University of Melbourne), we we're required to maintain our own style while being consistent. However, there are guidelines you can follow which are accepted in the wider C community.

Other than this stylistic choice, this has a small, important difference. difference lies in the scope and lifetime of the loop counter.

If you initialize the loop counter before the loop, it will have a larger scope. It will be accessible both inside and outside the loop, and its lifetime will extend beyond the loop.

```
int i;
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    // loop body
}
// i is still accessible here
```

In terms of performance, there is no difference between the two. The choice between them depends on whether you need to access the loop counter outside the loop.

You also ask about space taken by the program. You can dig a little bit deeper into the int data type and see that it will use the same number of bytes no matter where you declare it in your program.

I hope this helped.